# In DDD, why they often make use of methods instead of properties?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

In DDD examples I often see the use of methods where I would probably have used a property. Why is this?

For example (from [Strengthening your domain: Aggregate Construction](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2010/02/24/strengthening-your-domain-aggregate-construction/))

```
public class Order
{
    public bool IsLocal()
    {
       return Customer.Province == BillingProvince;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One argument for choosing methods instead of properties is when there would be any code that does something. If it just returns some internal field value then use property. If it has any logic inside or does any calculation use method. This makes it clearer to client of code that there is something happening when you call this method.

I think I've read in [CLR via CSharp](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735627045) that Microsoft regrets making `DateTime.Now` a property instead of method. It returns new value every time you call it. That should be method not property.

Comment: Agreed. Probably it's just the contrived examples causing this. No real DDD reason.

Answer (score 1):

There are no reasons for replacing getters with methods specific to DDD. The general guidelines apply here (do that when a heavy computation is performed or state is changed).

Setters are a different case though. Some people even consider them a code smell. You should get suspicious each time you see a setter. In an ideal case the state of the object is changed only in methods whose names coincide with verbs in the domain.